# Why size becomes bigger when using imagecreatefromjpeg / png / gif / bmp as needed to add watermark

Tags: php, image, image-uploading, watermark, image-size

My topic is about adding watermark to images using PHP code. Example is here http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php

I face a problem is that the example mentioned only deals with JPEG images only as it uses imagecreatefromjpeg() function.

I used this function I do not remember from where I got it. It creates image of other types png, bmp and gif.

```
function imageCreateFromAny($filepath){
    $type = exif_imagetype($filepath); // [] if you don't have exif you could use getImageSize()
    $allowedTypes = array(
        1,  // [] gif
        2,  // [] jpg
        3,  // [] png
        6   // [] bmp
    );
    if (!in_array($type, $allowedTypes)) {
        return false;
    }
    switch ($type) {
        case 1 :

            $im = imageCreateFromGif($filepath);
        break;
        case 2 :

            $im = imageCreateFromJpeg($filepath);
        break;
        case 3 :

            $im = imageCreateFromPng($filepath);
        break;
        case 6 :

            $im = imageCreateFromBmp($filepath);
        break;
    }   
    return $im; 
}
```

THE PROBLEM: The output image of the function is an image which its size number is multiplied by 4, I mean the size becomes bigger around 4 times. For example, if the function received the image as 94K, it outputs it around 380K.

I want to resolve the problem of maximizing the size number, I want to get the same image size as before the image size was input to the function  imageCreateFromAny($filepath)

Hint:
The below function is calling the above function

```
function Stamp($filename){




        // Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
        $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('../../style/images/stamp1.png');
//        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('../../gallery/black-white/'.$filename);
        $im = imageCreateFromAny('../../gallery/black-white/'.$filename);


        // Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
        $marge_right = 10;
        $marge_bottom = 10;
        $sx = imagesx($stamp);
        $sy = imagesy($stamp);

        // Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
        // width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
        imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

        // Output and free memory
//        header('Content-type: image/png');
//        imagepng($im);
        $filename_new = '../../gallery/black-white/'.$filename.'';
//        if (move_uploaded_file(imagepng($im), '../../gallery/black-white/2'   )) 
        imagepng($im, $filename_new);
        imagedestroy($im);


}
```

Comment: This particular function doesn't return "an image" at all, it returns an *image resource* whose size is a bit hard to measure. Where exactly are you turning this into a measurable image file?

Comment: jpeg size is non-deteriministic. You can't tell exactly how big the final file will be, because it depends entirely on the compression settings and the stucture of the image itself. a "noisy" image with lots of detail will produce a larger .jpg file than a simple image with large areas of "constant" color. if your new image is bigger than the original, then you either used a different jpeg quality setting, or introduced more noise.

Comment: please hold on. I will update the post. @deceze

Comment: I am not understanding what you saying, please be brief to help me. @MarcB

Comment: well, now that you've posted the actual code... you're saving as a png. png is (vaguely/roughly) like zip. it's lossless compression, and will almost always be bigger than a jpg of the same image. you can't compare png and jpg sizes and complain about png being bigger, because they serve different purposes. they might both be images, but it's like complaining a ferrari's faster than a yugo.

Comment: @MarcB i understand but I didn't hear so far how I get output as jpg and with same input size. That would be the answer I want.

Comment: "jpeg quality setting", "introduced more noise". you did get the answer, you just didn't read it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120548/discussion-between-abutaha-and-marc-b).

Answer (score 3):

You're saving the image to a PNG, which, yes, is often significantly larger than a JPEG, but also has higher quality. JPEG is a *lossy* format, which discards quality for a smaller file size. PNG is a *lossless* format, which retains all possible information and just tries to compress the data as much as it can. For an image with a lot of detail, that will result in massively bigger sizes than JPEG with a low quality setting.

Comment: so what? do you want me to update: imagepng(); ? What should I do it? Or what are your suggestions?

Comment: I changed imagepng() to imagejpeg() and I got half size. It is another problem to me. I want to output the same size as input.

Comment: Basically you cannot. You're re-compressing a lossy file format, you're not going to get the same size again, except perhaps by pure chance. You can control the JPEG quality with the quality parameter, which will influence the size; but there's fundamentally no "keep same size" option.

Comment: Uham, if different size and close to original size, no problem, but would be the image quality affected? if not, I tolerate getting more/less size but close to original size and with same quality. Glad to hear ur comment.

Comment: Image quality is most certainly affected if you recompress a lossy format. Each time you do so you lose a little more quality (or a lot, depending on your quality setting). The thing is, you don't know what the original quality setting was, and hence can't reproduce it. A small file saved at 50% quality and a large file saved at 99% quality are fundamentally indistinguishable programmatically. And even if you could detect the quality setting, saving a 50% image again at 50% will make it look really shoddy.

Comment: images are input into computer using a scanner. Does that gives you a hint about their quality settings, or at least all images should have same quality setting?

Comment: No hint whatsoever.